# Unable to access Trailhead

Tags: trailhead

Recently I quit a company but my trailhead account's email was my company mail id. Now when I tried to login to trailhead, it is asking for Verification Code sent to my company id which no longer exists. Please let me know what can be done to regain access to my trailhead account.

Comment: Log case in salesforce or discuss on twitter account https://twitter.com/trailhead

Comment: Raise a Case to Salesforce : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?support=home

Comment: I had a very similar issue and I opened a case to Salesforce and they solved.

Answer (score 0):

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Trailhead-Self-Service-Account-Merge

Please check this link for self-service-account-merge, If you have any other personal email connected to your account this will help in resolving the issue.

For example: if you had connected an email abc@gmail.com to your trailhead account, You could log in using abc@gmail.com and remove the corporate Id which isn't needed anymore. And create a new trailhead with the latest corp id and add abc@gmail.com under-connected emails. you will be prompted to merge. Merge and all your badges and points are in the new account with the latest corp Id as your primary email id.

Or you could choose to keep abc@gmail.com as your primary Id and corp id in email accounts.

Note: primary id is the email id that you want to utilize for connecting to the partner community.

Comment: please make sure you include the procedure from the link, since links may break. thanks